# Powershell to list specific user profiles

Tags: powershell, user-profile

Is there a way to list specific user profiles instead all the users?  Ex:  List all the accounts starting with IT.

It should list all the users with ITUser1,ITUser2, ect....

The following script shows how to retrieve all user profiles.
Thanks for any suggestions.

```
$mySiteUrl = "http://www.bing.com"

#Get site objects and connect to User Profile Manager service
$site = Get-SPSite $mySiteUrl
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context) 
$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()

foreach ($up in $profiles) {

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [Where cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) to filter the users.

```
$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator() | Where {$_.name -like "IT*"}
```

Note: This does the filtering after retrieving the full list.

Also

```
$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator() | Where {$_.MultiloginAccounts -like "domainname\adminID*"}
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan. I didn't have a chance to try it out until today, and it works. Here are the syntax: profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator() | Where {$_.MultiloginAccounts -like "domainname\adminID*"} –

Comment: can you use use an arry